# EMF: Overriding XSD

Tags: xsd, emf

I am writing XSD to generate Model Classes using EMF.

The XSD looks like:

`<xsd:complexType name="DerivedType">
    <xsd:complexContent mixed="false">
        <xsd:extension base="ParentType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element ...../>
            <xsd:element ...../>
        </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute .... />
       </xsd:extension>
   </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>`

Here the DerivedType is extending from ParentType.

ParentType contains another complex element 'cmplx'.

Now, I want to add another attribute to complex element ('cmplx').

I don't want to extend 'cmplx' as it will create a new class in EMF generated code against extending the 'cmplx' type.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an element or attribute defining its type as follows:

```
<xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
```

Can you be more specific? What kind of attribute would you like to add? Is it an attribute or is it an element?